# What is the simplest library to download files in C++

Tags: c++, windows-vista

I want to download files that I have the full URL address using my c++ program, which library is the best to do this?

I was wondering for a command like:

```
system("download [URL] [DESTINATION]");
```

or

```
download(URL,DESTINATION);
```

I am using Windows, sorry that I forgot to mention.

Comment: Which OS are you using, which toolkit?

Comment: Windows Vista, OMG sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2):

You have not mentioned the operating system, anyways you can do that using system function in `c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    system("wget url");
    return 0;
}
```

Change `url` to get the file you needed.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at curl

from curl site

> curl is a command line tool for transferring data with URL syntax, supporting DICT, FILE, >FTP, FTPS, Gopher, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, >SFTP, SMTP, SMTPS, Telnet and TFTP. curl supports SSL certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP uploading, HTTP form based upload, proxies, cookies, user+password authentication (Basic, Digest, NTLM, Negotiate, kerberos...), file transfer resume, proxy tunneling and a busload >of other useful tricks.

Its the best client side library available

http://curl.haxx.se/

Answer (score 1):

[`libcurl`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is one of the widely used multi-protocol network transfer libraries. It can be used for downloading files or pages over HTTP and lot of other protocols.

The command line client `curl` is built on top of the `libcurl` library.

Answer (score 0):

for a call to `system("command");` you could use some command line tools that can achieve a download. [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) and [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) are such tools. the later even provides an [API](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/) for C so you can write you own `download(...)` function.